# Is there any free directions REST API compatible with OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap

I failed to find any official docs if OpenStreetMap provide any API for directions. Maybe there is some other free service for this task?

Comment: hi did you found any free OpenStreetMap api for direction rather than google direction api

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing provided directly by the OpenStreetMap project, but there are other options provided using OpenSteeetMap data such as the [MapQuest Open Directions API Service](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/directions-service).

Comment: Seems that it doesn't work in Russia

Comment: Map quest direction api doesn't seems to free.

Comment: You're looking at their main API I expect - the open API that existed seven years ago is long gone.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the Open Route Service [https://openrouteservice.org/](https://openrouteservice.org)

It has an API ([docs](https://openrouteservice.org/dev/#/api-docs/)) that has a comprehensive description and is free.

Comment: This is a link-only answer. If the link dies, it will contain no information.

Comment: I disagree. This is useful.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I just added the home link so if the docs link changes, we can still reach service main page. Please reconsider your downvote.

Comment: At your request I've retracted my downvote, but I still think that this is [a link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/284827).

Comment: Thanks for this info.  As of 2021, this service is running and works well.

Answer (score 6):

In reference to your question and [Android draw route on openstreetmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528810/android-draw-route-on-openstreetmap) I found [YOURS](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/YOURS) api which is free for use.

> The routing API is open and freely available for everyone under the
>   condition that you don't overload the server. Overloading the server
>   in this context means: more then 1 request per second for sustained
>   periods of time.

Here is a sample request i used in replacement of Google's Direction Api:

http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php?flat=28.6337465&flon=77.35780799999999&tlat=28.6388179&tlon=77.3606496&format=geojson