# Android draw route on openstreetmap

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I am looking for a way to draw a route path on `openstreetmap` in my android app.
I only have the start and end points, however do not want just a straight line.
Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/YOURS The routing API is open and freely available for everyone under the condition that you don't overload the server. Overloading the server in this context means: more then 1 request per second for sustained periods of time

Answer (score 3):

For obtaining a route you can use one of the various [online routers for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers). Many of them offer a GPX export of the calculated route which you then can display in your application.

Comment: Also look out for offline router options for Android

Comment: Does that mean we need to use some 3rd party services like google's direction api or any unpaid service in order to get the turn by turn coordinate information? And plot the GeoPoints/PolyLine as an map overlay

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me. Yes, you will need *some* service to obtain directions. This can be an online service (provided by OSM, Google or someone else). Alternatively you can use an offline router. In this case you will need offline map data. In the end this all depends on your specific goals and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Open Street Map wiki, including the Traveling Salesman example:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Traveling_salesman

Comment: His question doesn't sound like it has anything to do with TSP.

Comment: @scai:  I was more just pointing him to the wiki.  The tsp is a good starting point, and it looked like he didn't have a clue where to start

Comment: But TSP is a very specific routing problem whereas he asked for a general solution. Nevertheless the wiki is a good starting point.